# TenantId Claim not being returned from IdentityServer4 to Client App

Tags: authentication, identityserver4

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661457/identityserver4-add-tenant-claim-after-authentication) question, I ended up using the `HttpContext.SignInAsync(string subject, Claim[] claims)` overload to pass the selected tenant id as a claim (defined as type "TenantId") after the user selects a Tenant.

I then check for this claim in my custom `AccountChooserResponseGenerator` class from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708564/identityserver4-custom-authorizeinteractionresponsegenerator) question to determine if the user needs to be directed to the Tenant Chooser page or not, as follows:

```
public override async Task<InteractionResponse> ProcessInteractionAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request, ConsentResponse consent = null)
        {
            var response = await base.ProcessInteractionAsync(request, consent);
            if (response.IsConsent || response.IsLogin || response.IsError)
                return response;

            if (!request.Subject.HasClaim(c=> c.Type == "TenantId" && c.Value != "0"))
                return new InteractionResponse
                {
                    RedirectUrl = "/Tenant"
                };

            return new InteractionResponse();
        }
```

The interaction is working and the user gets correctly redirected back to the Client app after selecting a Tenant.

However, on my client, I have the simple:

```
<dl>
            @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
            {
                <dt>@claim.Type</dt>
                <dd>@claim.Value</dd>
            }
        </dl>
```

snippet from the IdentityServer4 quickstarts to show the claims, and sadly, my TenantId claim is not there.

I have allowed for it in the definition of my Client on my IdentityServer setup, as follows:

```
var client = new Client
                {
... other settings here
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
                        "TenantId"
                    }
                };
```

What am I missing in order for this TenantId claim to become visible in my Client application?

EDIT:

Based on @d_f's comments, I have now added TentantId to my server's `GetIdentityResources()`, as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResources.Email(),
                new IdentityResources.Phone(),
                new IdentityResource("TenantId", new[] {"TenantId"})
            };
        }
```

And I have edited the client's `startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` to request this additional scope, as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    //other settings not shown

                    options.Scope.Add("TenantId");

                });
```

And still the only claims displayed on the client by the indicated snippet are:
[image: claims]

Edit 2: Fixed!

Finally @RichardGowan's answer worked.  And that is because (as brilliantly observed by @AdemCaglin) I was using IdentityServer's AspNetIdentity, which has it's own implementation of [IProfileService](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/blob/dev/src/ProfileService.cs), which kept dropping my custom TenantId claim, despite ALL these other settings).

So in the end, I could undo all those other settings...I have no mention of the TenantId claim in `GetIdentityResources`, no mention of it in `AllowedScopes` in the definition of the Client in my IdSrv, and no mention of it in the configuration of `services.AddAuthentication` on my client.

Comment: You've added "TenantId" as AllowedScope for your client, but you've not described that scope. Something like:
services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(new List<IdentityResource>
                {
                    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                    new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                    new IdentityResources.Email(),
                    new IdentityResource("TenantId", new[] {"TenantId"})
                })

Comment: and you have to request that additional scope in your client configuration

Comment: or simply `.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(GetIdentityResources())` and later: `public static List<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            /*Claims automatically included in OpenId scope*/
            var openIdScope = new IdentityResources.OpenId();
            openIdScope.UserClaims.Add("TenantId");
            /* Available scopes*/
            return new List<IdentityResource>{openIdScope, new IdentityResources.Profile(), new IdentityResources.Email(), /*etc*/};
        }`

Comment: @d_f thanks for your feedback...please see my edits indicating changes made to my setup...but still no TenantId claim on the client side?

Comment: Add `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken` setting to your client's configuration in IdSrv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide and register an implementation of `IProfileService` to issue your custom claim back to the client:

```
public class MyProfileService : IProfileService {
    public MyProfileService() {
    }

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context) {
        // Issue custom claim
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(context.Subject.Claims.First(c => c.Type == 
               "TenantId"));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context) {
        context.IsActive = true;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not necessary. The DefaultProfileService implementation already does that job. Custom profile service is amid for filtering or for issuing totally new claims not yet within the Subject.

Comment: As I mentioned, the default `IProfileService` implementation makes the same thing, since it has `context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);` inside. Seems, you performed some additional change or fix to make it work...

Comment: @d_f Probably OP uses identityserver with identity and this library has own iprofileservice implementation. You can see code https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/blob/dev/src/ProfileService.cs

Comment: @ademcaglin wow what a brilliant observation...I was not aware of that either!  But that is exactly it.

Comment: @ademcaglin, I agree, there are too many possibilities without seen the whole solution... that's why I've not rolled out my own answer... the answer should be complete : )

Comment: @ShawndeWet and now I guess so tough replacing the `ProfileService` from Identity is a step in a wrong direction (if you really need that Identity, and don't plan to implement your own UserStore). I could suggest to take the existing implementation as a base -- that would be more polite and straightforward for later support. At least... But more proper way could be extending UserClaimsFactory form the same package, or UserManager... I don't know, that's your project : )